# Writing a program that prints out the name of students with more than six quiz score

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to Python. Please help me out. From a `"score.txt"` file I have to print out the names of students that have more than 6 quiz scores. It is as follows

```
joe 10 15 20 30 40,
bill 23 16 19 22,
sue 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17,
grace 12 28 21 45 26 10,
john 14 32 25 16 89
```

My initial approach was like this to separate data from string

```
f=open("score.txt", "r")
f.readlines()[1:]
```

This gave me a list. How can I check the `len(elements)>=6` and then print the names?

Comment: You can use `.split()` to separate the individual scores from each line

Comment: but the output was from f.readlines(). How can I use .split() in f.readlines()? Because it is giving me error

Answer (score 0):

Since they are lines of data in the file and each line seperated by a space you can use string manipulation here

```py
f=open("score.txt", "r")
entries = f.readlines()

for entry in entries:
   # split entry by space, first is name, the rest are scores
   chunk = entry.split(' ')
   name = chunk[0]
   scores = chunk[1:]

   if len(scores) > 6:
      print(f'{name} had more than 6 quiz scores {len(scores)}')
```

Comment: What's the use of `f.readlines()[1:]`?  You're simply throwing away the first line of the text file…  I know that this is what the querent wrote in their post, but please consider that apparently the querent doesn't know too much about what they are doing… I suggest to write just `entries = f.readlines()`